# elisp - insert behaves not like message

Tags: elisp

i want to write a elisp function, that prints the result of some number multiplied by 7.

The following code works great, when i replace the "insert" with "message", but when using the code as it is down below it prints "The result is %d#", so it does not format the string properly. Why is this and how to fix the problem ?

```
(defun logbuch (number)       ; Interactive version.
   "Multiply NUMBER by seven."
   (interactive "p")
   (insert "The result is %d" (* 7 number))
   ;(message "good morning")
)
```

i execute the code with "C u 5 M x logbuch"

i tried to google it but found nothing helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap it in `format`.
Take the time to learn it, it's a very important function.

```
(defun logbuch (number)
   "Multiply NUMBER by seven."
   (interactive "p")
   (insert (format "The result is %d" (* 7 number)))
   ;(message "good morning")
   )
```

Comment: thanks that might work, but it does not answer the question why it works with "message"

Comment: Ok thank you, it worked and i will also take a look at the docstring as you said.